# Entity Framework 6, Repository pattern and Unit of Work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am learning Entity Framework and some design patterns such repository pattern and unit of work. I wrote a program that uses these patterns. In this class I have one DbContext object and I always use this static DbContext. Throughout my application's lifetime, there is only one DbContext object. Am I doing right using this way, think if there are lots of users. Will be any problem about database connections.

UI code:

```
UnitOfWork uow = GetUnitOfWork(); //There is only one uow object
uow.EmployeeRepository.Insert(new Employee
{
    Name = name,
    Surname = surname
});
```

GetUnitOfWork code:

```
private static UnitOfWork _uow;
public static UnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork()
{
    return _uow ?? (_uow = new UnitOfWork());
}
```

UnitOfWork code:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private static FollowerEntities _context;
    private DbContextTransaction _transaction;

    //repositories
    private EmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;


    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new FollowerEntities();
    }

    public EmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository
    {
        get { return _employeeRepository ?? (_employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository(_context)); }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Employee Repository

```
public class EmployeeRepository : GenericRepository<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeRepository(FollowerEntities entities)
        : base(entities)
    {

    }
}
```

Generic Repository

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private FollowerEntities _entities;


    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public GenericRepository()
    {

    }

    public GenericRepository(FollowerEntities entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
        table = _entities.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

    public T SelvectById(object id)
    {
        return table.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        table.Attach(obj);
        _entities.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = table.Find(id);
        table.Remove(existing);
    }
}
```

Comment: too many people have written articles describing how to write a repository over Entity Framework.  What most fail to realize is that Entity Framework is already a repository, and putting a repository on top of a repository only limits you from being able to use it's power directly.  Also, It is never a good idea to have a single UoW class that is shared among different objects, where one object could prematurely modify the database without other objects' knowledge.

Comment: here is one of many good articles on this subject: http://tech.pro/blog/1191/say-no-to-the-repository-pattern-in-your-dal

Comment: @AndrewCounts, you said "Also, It is never a good idea to have a single UoW class that is shared among different objects, where one object could prematurely modify the database without other objects' knowledge". But if I have many UoW it means I have many DbContext. And above situation may also occur in this way?

Comment: The problem is not with changes to the database; more, it's a problem with the expectations of objects.  Any object which interacts with a UoW should reasonably assume the UoW itself is consistent throughout the Work Cycle.  If you have a shared UoW, and multiple objects modify the UoW, it's impossible to know if you are, for example, creating a relationship with a now deleted object, since you aren't creating a transaction until the save action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static UnitOfWork _uow;
public static UnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork()
{
    return _uow ?? (_uow = new UnitOfWork());
}
```

Although technically correct, this won't be as useful as you think. You limit the API to a single instance of the UoW. Considering shared scenarios like ASP.NET, this method won't probably be used as often as you think. I suggest removing it.

```
public UnitOfWork()
{
    _context = new FollowerEntities();
}
```

This unnecessarily couples the context lifetime to UoW lifetime. Instead, separate them:

```
public UnitOfWork( FollowerEntities context )
{
    _context = context;
}
```

This way, other means of lifetime management (IoC container possibly) could be used.

```
_transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
_context.SaveChanges();
_transaction.Commit();
```

Are you sure saves should always be wrapped in a transaction? What if another transaction exists on the same connection and you want to reuse it?

And the biggest issue - neither the UoW nor repositories are abstracted (with interfaces). This means that the client is still coupled to the sole implementation. You have just created a wrapped over Entity Framework but you can't benefit from it, for example, you can't switch to another implementation without rewriting it. I don't see any solid point in it, beside just excercising.